# New to Python and struggling to understand specific code

Tags: python

I am new to python and cannot figure out what this code does:

```
df.loc[(df['col1'] == y),'col2'] = 1
```

Could you kindly help me to understand it?

Answer (score 1):

It sets all elements of the column `col2` in the dataframe to one, if the value of column `col1` in the same row equals `y`.

In pseudo-code:

```
for row in dataframe:
    if row[col1] == y:
        row[col2] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[df.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is used to Access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array.

When you are passing two parameters which will access a particular row column value, where you have `df['col1']` which should be equal to `y` and it grabs all the rows matching the condition and then selects the rows with column values of `col2` and then set the value to `1` to that particular location in the data frame.

Assuming `y = 10`

```
col1    col2
   1       2
  10       5  <-- (Select this first) 
   7       8
```

```
col1    col2
   1       2
  10       1  <-- (Change the `col2` value to `1`) 
   7       8
```